# Joining two accounts to each other?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

I have two accounts on Stack Overflow. Is there any way to join them to each other? 
I mean, is there any any way to move **questions** and **answers** from one account to another account?

I want to have all of my questions in a single account. Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this would to merge the accounts - using the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form - but that would leave **all** of your questions **and** answers on a single account.

I do have to question why you want separate accounts for questions and answers. While this isn't strictly against the rules, it does sound somewhat odd.

If you are using the second account to answer questions from the first then this **is** against the rules.

Comment: I had an account and it was blocked to ask new questions, so I made a new account, is that illegal?

Comment: Yep, don't circumvent bans with multiple accounts.

Comment: @Bart what now? should I delete it? Is it possible?

Comment: @user3739919 get the accounts merged. If the new account has good questions then the block *may* be lifted.